# asp net core auth without http context. (JWT)

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, jwt, authorization, decorator

I have a question about auth in .net core. I need your advices. I have handlers (command or query) which can be invoked from web api controllers or they can be invoked from Kafka consumers.

Since handlers can be invoked from Web API controllers or Kafka consumers I want to centralize the auth logic as decorator to handlers.

Example.

```
public class CreateUserCommand : ICommand
{
   public string Email {get; set;}
   public string Password {get; set;}
}

public class CreateUserCommandHandler : ICommandHandler< CreateUserCommand >
{
    public void Handle(CreateUserCommand command)
    {
      // some business logic
    }
}

public class AuthDecoator : ICommandHandler<TCommand>
{
   public AuthDecoator (ICommandHandler<TCommand> decoratee)

    public void Handle(CreateUserCommand command)
    {
      // handle auth, if valid 
      decoratee.Handle(command);
    }
}

// From Web API
public class UsersController : ControllerBase
{
   public IActioneResult Register(string email, string password)
   {
       createUserCommandHandler.Handler(new CreateUserCommand { Email = email, 
         Password = password })
   }
}

public class RegisterUser
{
   public string Email {get; set;}
   public string Password {get; set;}
}

// From Consumer
public class RegisterConsumer : ConsumerBase
{
   public ConsumeResult Consume(RegisterUser)
   {
       createUserCommandHandler.Handler(new CreateUserCommand { Email = email, 
         Password = password })
   }
}
```

By this way I will have a chance to secure all types of calls such as Kafka consume, http, or batch jobs

So my question is

1. Is it good idea to have authontication as decorator to handlers ?
2. if so how can I write my own 'AuthenticationHandler' without http context ? My functional codes should not aware of transportation protocol such as http/s

I checked options such as 'AuthenticationHandler' but all depends on http context.

Comment: When you catch a message from Kafka, I don't expect is has a JWT token inside. A message it is just a notification that smth happened within a system. It may contain some sort of a user context (like userId or userName), but not a token. If you want to - you may use this data to decide how to process the message, but it has nothing in common with authentication.

Comment: Your handlers should rely on some sort of an abstract "execution context", which in the case of http-less context will be populated with a "system user".

Comment: @Artem I know Kafka message does not have any token bf default. We can include token as part of message but it is not good idea. Consumer is responsible for to get token from Identity server and call handlers.

Comment: @Artem for second comment. Yes that is what I am planning to do. My handlers has request context and consumers will issue token and add it to request context to be validated while handling process of handlers